How to setup vim-lsp-config and java-debug adapter working on java
I'm in University and we have started learning OOP using java{Help my sanity}. I am able to get completions and snippets working but I don't know how to configure Mason and Mason-Lsp-config to work with LspConfig. I am using lazy.nvim btw if that helps. I am in windows for now but answers specific archlinux might not be a problem as I also plan to be writing some of this java code there
